# Can I be notified of cookie changes in client side JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, cookies

Can I somehow follow changes to cookies (for my domain) in my client side JavaScript? For example, is there a function that gets called if a cookie gets changed, deleted or added?

In order of preference:

- standard cross browser
- cross browser
- browser specific
- extension / plugin

Why? Because cookies I depend on in window / tab #1 can get changed in window / tab #2.

I found out that Chrome allows extensions to be notified of cookie changes. But that's my least favorite option.

Comment: Cookie cannot initiate communication to their respective webpage. It is the webpage's responsibility which should keep track of cookie's content.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**Method 1: Periodic Polling**

Poll `document.cookie`

```js
function listenCookieChange(callback, interval = 1000) {
  let lastCookie = document.cookie;
  setInterval(()=> {
    let cookie = document.cookie;
    if (cookie !== lastCookie) {
      try {
        callback({oldValue: lastCookie, newValue: cookie});
      } finally {
        lastCookie = cookie;
      }
    }
  }, interval);
}
```

Usage

```js
listenCookieChange(({oldValue, newValue})=> {
  console.log(`Cookie changed from "${oldValue}" to "${newValue}"`);
}, 1000);

document.cookie = 'a=1; Path=/';
```

**Method 2: API Interception**

Intercept `document.cookie`

```js
(()=> {
  let lastCookie = document.cookie;
  // rename document.cookie to document._cookie, and redefine document.cookie
  const expando = '_cookie';
  let nativeCookieDesc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Document.prototype, 'cookie');
  Object.defineProperty(Document.prototype, expando, nativeCookieDesc);
  Object.defineProperty(Document.prototype, 'cookie', {
    enumerable: true,
    configurable: true,
    get() {
      return this[expando];
    },
    set(value) {
      this[expando] = value;
      // check cookie change
      let cookie = this[expando];
      if (cookie !== lastCookie) {
        try {
          // dispatch cookie-change messages to other same-origin tabs/frames
          let detail = {oldValue: lastCookie, newValue: cookie};
          this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('cookiechange', {
            detail: detail
          }));
          channel.postMessage(detail);
        } finally {
          lastCookie = cookie;
        }
      }
    }
  });
  // listen cookie-change messages from other same-origin tabs/frames
  const channel = new BroadcastChannel('cookie-channel');
  channel.onmessage = (e)=> {
    lastCookie = e.data.newValue;
    document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('cookiechange', {
      detail: e.data
    }));
  };
})();
```

**Usage**

```js
document.addEventListener('cookiechange', ({detail: {oldValue, newValue}})=> {
  console.log(`Cookie changed from "${oldValue}" to "${newValue}"`);
});

document.cookie = 'a=1; Path=/';
```

**Notes**

1. not for IE
2. require BroadcastChannel polyfill for Safari

#### Conclusion

```
| Metric \ Method  | Periodic Polling            | API Interception |
| ---------------- | --------------------------- | ---------------- |
| delay            | depends on polling interval | instant          |
| scope            | same-domain                 | same-origin      |
```

Comment: Does this only works for me if is set the cookies in the browser console but not if the cookie is set by a set-cookie response header

Comment: There is experimental Cookie Store API which is full-featured, https://wicg.github.io/cookie-store/#example-1ce710fe

Comment: Unfortunately for now Cookie Store API does not seem to be fully cross-browser.

Answer (score 34):

One option is to write a function that periodically checks the cookie for changes:

```
var checkCookie = function() {

    var lastCookie = document.cookie; // 'static' memory between function calls

    return function() {

        var currentCookie = document.cookie;

        if (currentCookie != lastCookie) {

            // something useful like parse cookie, run a callback fn, etc.

            lastCookie = currentCookie; // store latest cookie

        }
    };
}();

window.setInterval(checkCookie, 100); // run every 100 ms
```

- This example uses a closure for persistent memory. The outer function is executed immediately, returning the inner function, and creating a private scope.
- [window.setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setInterval)

Comment: seems like its my only portable option

Comment: It seems like this might be a thing soon?
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/cookies/onChanged

Comment: @Worthy7 That looks like API for browser extensions, not websites

Comment: shouldn't it be window.setInterval(checkCookie(), 100);

Comment: @d7my `checkCookie` is immediately invoked when instantiated and returns a fn, so no, you don't need to invoke it in the `setInterval`

Answer (score 24):

We can use the [`CookieStore`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CookieStore) API:

```js
cookieStore.addEventListener('change', ({changed}) => {
    for (const {name, value} of changed) {
        console.log(`${name} was set to ${value}`);
    }
});
```

Comment: That is the ideal way - but not fully supported by all browsers - https://caniuse.com/?search=cookie%20store%20api

Comment: It also requires https

Comment: This is a quick and clean option but unfortunately doesn't notify about cookies being deleted.

Comment: This answer is futurproof :)

Comment: Using an API that's not supported in Firefox should be a no-go.

Answer (score 8):

I think my way is better. I wrote a custom event for detect when cookie is chanced:

```
const cookieEvent = new CustomEvent("cookieChanged", {
  bubbles: true,
  detail: {
    cookieValue: document.cookie,
    checkChange: () => {
      if (cookieEvent.detail.cookieValue != document.cookie) {
        cookieEvent.detail.cookieValue = document.cookie;
        return 1;
      } else {
        return 0;
      }
    },
    listenCheckChange: () => {
      setInterval(function () {
        if (cookieEvent.detail.checkChange() == 1) {
          cookieEvent.detail.changed = true;
          //fire the event
          cookieEvent.target.dispatchEvent(cookieEvent);
        } else {
          cookieEvent.detail.changed = false;
        }
      }, 1000);
    },
    changed: false
  }
});

/*FIRE cookieEvent EVENT WHEN THE PAGE IS LOADED TO
 CHECK IF USER CHANGED THE COOKIE VALUE */

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (e) {
  e.target.dispatchEvent(cookieEvent);
});

document.addEventListener("cookieChanged", function (e) {
  e.detail.listenCheckChange();
  if(e.detail.changed === true ){
    /*YOUR CODE HERE FOR DO SOMETHING 
      WHEN USER CHANGED THE COOKIE VALUE */
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the workaround! `cookieValue: document.cookie` should be initialized to `cookieValue:  ""`. I tested locally

Answer (score 7):

If the code that manipulated the cookies is yours, you can use   `localStorage` for tracking changed with events. for example, you can store a junk on the localStorage to trigger an event on the other tabs.

for example

```
var checkCookie = function() {

var lastCookies = document.cookie.split( ';' ).map( function( x ) { return x.trim().split( /(=)/ ); } ).reduce( function( a, b ) { 
        a[ b[ 0 ] ] = a[ b[ 0 ] ] ? a[ b[ 0 ] ] + ', ' + b.slice( 2 ).join( '' ) :  
        b.slice( 2 ).join( '' ); return a; }, {} );


return function() {

    var currentCookies =  document.cookie.split( ';' ).map( function( x ) { return x.trim().split( /(=)/ ); } ).reduce( function( a, b ) { 
        a[ b[ 0 ] ] = a[ b[ 0 ] ] ? a[ b[ 0 ] ] + ', ' + b.slice( 2 ).join( '' ) :  
        b.slice( 2 ).join( '' ); return a; }, {} );


    for(cookie in currentCookies) {
        if  ( currentCookies[cookie] != lastCookies[cookie] ) {
            console.log("--------")
            console.log(cookie+"="+lastCookies[cookie])
            console.log(cookie+"="+currentCookies[cookie])
        }

    }
    lastCookies = currentCookies;

};
}();
 $(window).on("storage",checkCookie); // via jQuery. can be used also with VanillaJS


// on the function changed the cookies

document.cookie = ....
window.localStorage["1"] = new Date().getTime(); // this will trigger the "storage" event in the other tabs.
```

Comment: this is very interesting - using localStorage as a communication mechanism between browser windows open to the same 'app'

Answer (score 1):

Slightly improved (shows a console.log for each changed cookie):

```
var checkCookie = function() {

var lastCookies = document.cookie.split( ';' ).map( function( x ) { return x.trim().split( /(=)/ ); } ).reduce( function( a, b ) { 
        a[ b[ 0 ] ] = a[ b[ 0 ] ] ? a[ b[ 0 ] ] + ', ' + b.slice( 2 ).join( '' ) :  
        b.slice( 2 ).join( '' ); return a; }, {} );


return function() {

    var currentCookies =  document.cookie.split( ';' ).map( function( x ) { return x.trim().split( /(=)/ ); } ).reduce( function( a, b ) { 
        a[ b[ 0 ] ] = a[ b[ 0 ] ] ? a[ b[ 0 ] ] + ', ' + b.slice( 2 ).join( '' ) :  
        b.slice( 2 ).join( '' ); return a; }, {} );


    for(cookie in currentCookies) {
        if  ( currentCookies[cookie] != lastCookies[cookie] ) {
            console.log("--------")
            console.log(cookie+"="+lastCookies[cookie])
            console.log(cookie+"="+currentCookies[cookie])
        }

    }
    lastCookies = currentCookies;

};
}();

window.setInterval(checkCookie, 100);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the new [CookieStore](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CookieStore) and want the support of all browsers, you can install a (speculative) polyfill like the following: https://github.com/markcellus/cookie-store