# Using value returned from function in react component (auto-update)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I wish to use the value returned from this function:

```
const quantity = () => {
    let cookies = document.cookie.split("?");
    return cookies.length;
}
```

in my react component:

```
const cart_button = (
    <Mfont>{quantity}</Mfont>
);
```

`<Mfont>` is a standard span element styled with styled-components;

```
console.log(cookies.length)
```

gives me a number based on its length as expected, but I can't figure out how to insert it to my component and update every time a `cookie.length` increases.

Comment: React components only update when their `props` or `state` changes. So you need to either supply this `quantity` to the component as props, or store it in the state. I can't say any more without seeing the rest of your component(s).

Answer (score 2):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14344716/1287643), the most reliable way still in 2019 to detect changes in cookies is to check `document.cookie` [on interval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval).

In React 16.8, we have [`useEffect` hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) that we could use together with [`useState` hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) to run a function on interval and cause the component to update when the value of `document.cookie` has been updated, like

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const MyComponent = props => {
  const [latestCookie, setLatestCookie] = useState(document.cookie);

  useEffect(() => {
    const detectCookieUpdate = document.cookie !== latestCookie && setLatestCookie(document.cookie);
    const interval = window.setInterval(detectCookieUpdate, 1000);

    return () => window.clearInterval(interval);
  });

  return (
    <Mfont>{quantity()}</Mfont>
  );
};
```

This way we run a function every 1 second that checks if the value of `document.cookie` is equal to the previous value. Since the value is always a string, it's safe to use strict comparison operator `===` and not do any checks on top of that. When the values don't match, we run `setLatestCookie` provided by the state hook, causing the component to render again, and therefore making use of `quantity` function that will run again.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to pass length value as props to your component?  Then you can assign that value to the component state.  When state changes do whatever you want.