# when I change the cookie Expires / Max-Age to previous then current time from chrome dev tools application

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cookies, google-chrome-devtools, browser-api

I opened the chrome dev tool and from application `Cookies`, I changed the Cookie `Expires / Max-Age` to previous time then current time.

My question is when i change the `Expires / Max-Age`, its instantly reflecting and logged-out from website.

if logout functionality implemented at code level then how can we listen for cookie change and how can we achieve this functionality?

Comment: Polling periodically: [can i be notified of cookie changes in client side javascript](//stackoverflow.com/q/14344319)

Comment: i got it thanks @wOxxOm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it from [What do browsers do with expired cookies?](http://%20%20https://superuser.com/questions/356265/what-do-browsers-do-with-expired-cookies/356266)

and [from](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14344716/6431689)

```
var checkCookie = function() {

var lastCookie = document.cookie; // 'static' memory between function calls

return function() {

    var currentCookie = document.cookie;

    if (currentCookie != lastCookie) {

        // something useful like parse cookie, run a callback fn, etc.

        lastCookie = currentCookie; // store latest cookie

    }
};
}();

window.setInterval(checkCookie, 100); // run every 100 ms
```