# Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type '{}'

Tags: angular

I have the following problem where I am trying to get cookies from my browser however I need to get them as they appear. Some of them don't appear instantly so I am trying to use the below code to get them as they come. The error I am seeing in my editor is:

> Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type '{}'

```
import { CookieService } from 'ngx-cookie-service';

this._cookieService.getAll().subscribe((result) => {
  console.log(result);
});
```

Can someone please assist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ngx-cookie-service`'s getAll() method returns object not Observable.

It is: **getAll(): {}**

Simply use:

```
result = this._cookieService.getAll();
```

Check [Documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-cookie-service)

Answer (score 2):

Corresponding to the documentation the getAll function returns a map with the key value pairs. So no need to subscribe to it.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-cookie-service

```
var result = this._cookieService.getAll();
```

If you want to get notified of cookie changes you might end up writing a function that periodically checks for changes like suggested in other answers here or on other questions around: [can i be notified of cookie changes in client side javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14344319/can-i-be-notified-of-cookie-changes-in-client-side-javascript)

ngx-cookie-service doesnt provide any helper to reach that (nor does any of the other cookie helper libraries I found by a little research).

Answer (score 1):

You could write a service with a polling function based on the rxjs timer(), that checks the cookies continuously:

```
 private timer$: Subscription = new Subscription();

 public polling(frequency = 1000 * 60 * 5) {
        this.timer$.unsubscribe();
        this.timer$ = timer(0, frequency).subscribe(
            () => this.result = this._cookieService.getAll();
        );
    }
```

I hope this approach helps you!