# Maximum call stack size exceeded in defineProperty (Document.prototype)(Javascript + Cookie + Vue )

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, cookies

I am trying to get and set Cookie change in Javascript.

```
onMounted( async () => {
   const expando = ref('_cookie');
   const nativeCookieDesc: any = 
   ref(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Document.prototype, 'cookie'));
   Object.defineProperty(Document.prototype, expando.value, 
   nativeCookieDesc.value)
   Object.defineProperty(Document.prototype, 'cookie', {
      enumerable: true,
      configurable: true,
      get() {
        return this[expando.value];
      },
      async set(value) {
        try {
           this[expando.value] = value;
           return;
        } catch {
          //
        }
     }
   })
}
```

But I am getting an error "Maximum call stack size exceeded" at this[expando.value].

Maybe I use Document.prototype should this error.
Thanks for help

Comment: So what is `expando.value`?

Comment: An `async` setter doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I using Vue. expando.value is "_cookie"

Comment: Is this your own code? It looks quite similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63952971/1048572).

Comment: It doesn't really make sense to use a Vue `ref` for the `expando` property name.

Comment: Right. But i'm getting error "Maximum call stack size exceeded in defineProperty" when i save code and run document.cookie

Comment: I think Document.prototype is the cause of the error.