# Detect cookies cleared by user

Tags: javascript, session, cookies, session-cookies

I wanna detect when a user clears his cookies or session storage. Can JavaScript detect such event? I wanna detect which user clears the cookies

Comment: I don't know some event or API for this, but I think you can try to inject code which will check the cookies or SessionStorage at intervals

Comment: @Kirill thank you very much for suggesting a way. But I think that might slow down the code. And I can't get exact time the user cleared the cookies. Is there any other way? Please tell me if there is any. It will be more helpful to me. Thank You.

Comment: Today i found similar ask https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14344319/can-i-be-notified-of-cookie-changes-in-client-side-javascript
Most popular answer is about interval polling. I think there no another way

Comment: Also you should visit https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/cookies/onChanged You can solve problem with cookies in firefox